# Android 13 storage Permission Issue

Tags: java, android, permissions

```
        File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Reporwt.pdf");
    if(!file2.exists()) {
        try {
            boolean created = file2.createNewFile();
            Log.i("download", "File created? " + created);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("download", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I am trying to create a new file inside the internal storage of the device. When I am running this code on device running Android 13, I am getting "Operation not permitted" Error.

How do I create new files and directories inside the Internal Storage of the device in Android 13?

I tried all the below permissions but it didn't worked.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
```

Comment: use `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` instead of `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. also from android 11 api level 30 this permission is not longer sufficient to access the entire external storage. To create files and directories inside the app's internal storage, you don't need any specific permissions because the internal storage is private to your app

Answer (score 0):

use **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** instead of **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**. also from Android 11 API level 30 this permission is not longer sufficient to access the entire external storage. To create files and directories inside the app's internal storage, you don't need any specific permissions because the internal storage is private to your app.

try this code:

```
File file2 = new File(getFilesDir(), "Reporwt.pdf");

if (!file2.exists()) {
    try {
        boolean created = file2.createNewFile();
        Log.i("download", "File created? " + created);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("download", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

***getFilesDir()*** returns the path to your app's internal storage directory. You don't need additional permissions for this.

If you really want to create files on external storage, you need to use the Storage Access Framework (SAF) or the MediaStore API.

Answer (score 0):

> > new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Reporwt.pdf");

Change to:

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectoryDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "Reporwt.pdf");
```

So use any of the public directories on external storage that are already there.